# screenrc subshell for every window

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

.screenrc:

```
shell -${SHELL}
caption always "%n(%t) %= %{b}@%H[%l] : %{r}%c:%s"
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
termcap  xterm 'AF=\E[3%dm:AB=\E[4%dm'
terminfo xterm 'AF=\E[3%p1%dm:AB=\E[4%p1%dm'
startup_message off

screen -t server 0 rails s
screen -t spork 1 bundle exec spork
screen -t dev_log tail -f ./log/test.log
```

Pressing Ctrl+C in any of the screen windows above destroys it. I would like to have subshell for every so if I press Ctrl+C than I just exit to that subshell.

Right now I'm running `screen` and creating all windows above manually,  renaming them and it works great. I can terminate any program on any window, do something else and run it again. What I want to achieve is to have that set-up to run with just one command.

Comment: a shell exit when ctrl + D not C crtl C quit the running app

Comment: ctrl+C closes the app that's running in the window and screen closes that window than too

Comment: what is your default shell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to create another related question [How to keep Bash running after command execution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution) to just forget about big picture and focus on the main problem. Worked as intended and finally there were presented 3 ways to achieve the goal:

1. [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution#123105) which was not bad
2. [portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution#123112) (POSIX)
3. [simple](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution#123192)

and I choose to use 3rd one that way:

~/.run_screen:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash -i <<<"$*; exec </dev/tty"
```

~/.screenrc:

```
screen -t server 1 ${HOME}/.run_screen rails s
screen -t spork 2 ${HOME}/.run_screen bundle exec spork
screen -t dev_log 3 ${HOME}/.run_screen tail -f ./log/development.log
screen -t test_log 4 ${HOME}/.run_screen tail -f ./log/test.log
screen -t bash 0
```

Answer (score 2):

How about instead of a subshell, just open a new one when your app finishes?

```
screen -t htop bash -i -c "htop && bash"
```