# Can I specify a custom command before launching interactive bash session?

Tags: bash

> **Please note:** Although this question is essentially the same as [this linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution), I did not mark it as "solving my problem" because the answers provided there are not very satisfactory. The answer I accepted below is cleaner and simpler. Take a look!

I know how to pass `bash` a custom command to execute, e.g. like this:

```
bash -c "/bin/echo hello"
```

When I do this, `bash` executes the argument of `-c` and then exits. How can I get it to give me an interactive prompt when I'm done? Adding `-i` has no effect. I don't want to write the custom commands into a file that `.bashrc` always reads.

I've been making do with `bash -c "commands; exec bash -i"`, but it's not ideal since it starts `bash` twice. Is there a way to get the same effect while starting `bash` only once?

Comment: Well, the question is admittedly the same, but I didn't like any of the answers given there. I just accepted a far better answer. Not sure what the recommended course of action is for this type of duplication...

Comment: I agree that the accepted answer is a better answer than those on the duplicate question.

Comment: Update: I asked for guidance about this situation [on meta.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4231/23344) It turns out that if you like the answer(s) here better than those in the original question, it's possible to mark the older question as a duplicate of the newer one. I see there are some votes here to reopen, so I'll leave it up to you all. I'm just glad the question was open long enough for @Paul's great answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `--init-file` option like this `bash --init-file <(echo "echo hello")`. This will not source your `.bashrc` file at all. If you want the `.bashrc` file sourced you can add that like this `bash --init-file <(echo ". ~/.bashrc; echo hello")`. Or you can put all the commands you want to execute in a file and use `bash --init-file file_with_commands`

Comment: I like this! Much cleaner than redirecting from `/dev/tty` as in the linked question. Yes, I need to run `.bashrc` to have a fully functional interactive bash. Gotta try out your idea a bit...

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! You should add it to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution) too, which asks the same thing.