# How can I get colors when executing `bash -c`?

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

No colors are displayed when running `bash -c "ls -l"` (CentOS 7.2). I have an obscure reason to want to show the colors after all. Can I disable this... color suppression?

---

For anyone wondering about my obscure use case: I'm running the Parcellite clipboard manager, which supports "actions" in a context menu, and one of the actions I've defined is "Run terminal command" which opens a new terminal and runs a command stored on the clipboard. It is implemented in the following way (so that the command is allowed to contain all special characters except apostrophe):

```
# Parcellite recognizes %s only once; store in a variable to use twice
CMD='%s' gnome-terminal -e "$SHELL -c 'echo \\\$ \"\$CMD\"; eval \$CMD; exec $SHELL'"
# Or equivalently....
CMD='%s' gnome-terminal -e $SHELL' -c "echo \$ "$CMD"; eval $CMD; exec $SHELL"'
```

Because `gnome-terminal` can only run a single command and doesn't understand things like `&&`, I need to call `bash -c` (`$SHELL -c`) in order to interpret the command correctly and keep the shell running afterward (and since bash [doesn't directly support that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/how-to-keep-bash-running-after-command-execution) I have to also sneak in `exec $SHELL` at the end.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A somewhat more general-purpose answer is
to change `bash -c` to `bash -ci`. 
The `-i` option puts the shell into “interactive” mode,
which causes it to read the user’s `.bashrc` file and process aliases.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that colors are suppressed when you call `ls` that way, it's that colors are not enabled.

Your normal shell likely defines an alias for `ls` that includes `--color=tty` to enable colors, so just use that option when you call `ls`.

Comment: I see, bash aliases are disabled in `bash -c`. `bash -c "ls -l --color=tty"` works as expected. It's easy to forget that `ls` doesn't really mean `ls`!